# Dificuldade com If/ Else

Tags: c, c++

Olá! Tudo bom? 
Estou tendo um problema quando vou executar meu programa, é um programa para calcular quatro medias e dividir por quatro, e é necessário fazer isso utilizando If e Else, porem quando executo, o programa lê a primeira condição, e se a entrada do if for Else o programa lê normalmente, porem quando o "Aluno" é aprovado o programa executa o printf de APROVADOe em seguida executa o Printf de REPROVADO, sendo que se ele foi aprovado, não era para executar o reprovado. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main () {

//VARIAVEIS
float media, nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, recMedia, receberec;

printf("\n VAMOS CALCULAR SUA NOTA\n");
printf("\nPRESSIONE ENTER...\n");
getch();

//ENTRADA DE DADOS
printf("\n---------------------------\n");
printf("\nDIGITE SUA PRIMEIRA NOTA\n");
scanf("%f", &nota1);
printf("\nDIGITE SUA SEGUNDA NOTA\n");
scanf("%f", &nota2);
printf("\nDIGITE SUA TERCEIRA NOTA\n");
scanf("%f", &nota3);
printf("\nDIGITE SUA QUARTA NOTA\n");
scanf("%f", &nota4);

printf("\n---------------------------\n");
printf("\nPRESSIONE ENTER PARA CALCULAR\n");
getch();

//ENTRADA DE PROCESSAMENTO

printf("\nPRONTO JA VALIDAMOS SUA MEDIA!\nQUE RUFEM OS TAMBORES...\n");
media = (nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4)/4;
printf("\nSUA MEDIA:\t%.2f", media);
printf("\n---------------------------\n");

if (media>=7) {

    printf("\n\tAPROVADO!\n%.2f", media);

    }

    else {

        printf("\n\tREPROVADO!\n");
        printf("\nINSIRA SUA NOTA DE EXAME:");
        scanf("%f",&recMedia);
        printf("\nMEDIA DE EXAME:\t\n%.2f", recMedia);

    }

    receberec = (recMedia+media)/2;
    if (receberec>=7) {

        printf("\n\tAPROVADO EXAME!\n%.2f", receberec);

    } 

    else {

        printf ("\n\tREPROVADO EXAME!\n%.2f", receberec);
    }

printf("\n---------------------------\n");

getch();
printf("\nFIM\n");
system ("PAUSE");
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Por exemplo se o aluno tira 10 de media, o programa mostra que ele foi aprovado, mais também executa  a parte de reprovado em exame.

Comment: **Matheus**, você pode [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/329843/edit) a pergunta e descrever o problema, leia o [tour] para saber como funciona o site, caso necessite de ajuda sobre como utilizar a ferramenta, acesse a [help].

Comment: Oppa! Sim, Muito obrigado pela atenção... Já editei!

Comment: O problema é que você mostra o resultado do exame de qualquer forma, então automaticamente se a pessoa é aprovada, ela é reprovada no exame (pois será considerado o "zero" do exame). Precisa condicionar o teste do exame à reprovação apenas.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui resolução do problema, era exatamente isso!

Comment: Se o problema foi resolvido, dê um upvote no comentário do Bacco.

Answer (score 0):

Você não está dando um valor inicial a `recMedia`. Quando tem o resultado "APROVADO" no primeiro 'if', não tem jeito saber qual é o valor de `recMedia`.

Dê um valor inicial a todos os variaveis.